# Check database entry is null or not, In Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to check if `total_invoiced` field is has a value in sales_flat_order table in Magento. How can I check It?

My code in grid is,

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFilter('total_invoiced','notnull');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

I need to add orders having in value in `total_invoiced` field into a collection. How could I? Please share If anyone knows a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not quite sure, but this might be helpful:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('total_invoiced',array('notnull' => true));
```

Comment: A slight change, `addFilter` should be `addFieldToFilter`. Then It Worked! Thanks.